# Как выбрать правильный фильтр для сортировки событий в Splunk?

Tags: логирование

Есть лог, в котором описаны некие события :

```
5/12/18
11:09:45.880 AM 
22-03-2017 11:09:45,388 [INFO ] - add_application
Context: device_platform=windows phone_work_ext...............
5/12/18
11:09:45.860 AM 
22-03-2017 11:09:45,386 [INFO ] - id=8ee535c085ba515761234fc1b6522c3f
Context: device_platform=windows phone_work_ext..............
5/12/18
11:09:40.251 AM 
22-03-2017 11:09:40,251 [INFO ] - add_application
Context: device_platform=windows phone_work_ext.................
```

Какой поисковый запрос нужно сделать в Splunk, чтобы отобразился список только уникальных событий без повторений ?

По сути отфильтровать можно по трём строчкам до слова [INFO ] в каждом событии, но я не понимаю как это сделать, получается только текущую дату указать в качестве фильтра - 5/12/18 при помощи `%D` ,согласно их [документации](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.2.6/Data/Configuretimestamprecognition) можно вроде и время до тысячных засунуть в фильтр, указав `%H:%M:%S.%3N` , однако у меня при попытке так сделать возвращает пустоту.

Answer (score 0):

`dedup` - этот оператор позволяет схлопнуть события, с одним и тем же  значением.